# Elasticsearch regexp versus exists in must_not

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to have a more generic type of query that I can use to restrict my results to when a field is present.

I know that [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) works, like so:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "fieldname"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd really like to have a regular expression or at least wildcard matching, instead of the full match `exists` requires.

This is the regexp that I assumed would work, but doesn't:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "regexp": {
                "fieldname": {
                "value": "[*]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead I get back **ALL** results. I expected to get the exclusion of those results where the field does not exist.

Is there a regex query that will do this (and why does what I've tried not do what I'd expect)?

Ideally, I'm just trying to replicate what query_string_query is doing with: NOT filename:*

Comment: are you referencing the `regexp` query? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html I can't find `regex` but it might be b/c of an older ES version or something on my end

Comment: yes, sorry...  I'll correct.

Comment: @DavidSteiner I'm not sure what you mean when you say `I'd really like to have a regular expression or at least wildcard matching, instead of the full match exists requires.`. Can you provide a sample doc or two that you want to match/not match? You could require both that a field exists, and if it does, require it to match a regexp query using a bool query.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it may have been a lack of my understanding what the correct regular expression would be to "line up with" (be the equivalent of) exists.
The following actually does seem to mimic "exists":
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "regexp": {
                "fieldname": {
                "value": ".+"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}